# png image support and pdftools

Tags: auctex, images, pdf-tools

I have pdftools install and wish to use it with auctex. However, I cannot view the pdf as I get the error:

```
PNG image supported not compiled into Emacs
```

Output is simply the raw pdf.

I am using emacs 25.3 and running emacs Windows 10.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have been able to resolve this at least for Emacs25.3 on Windows 10.

In short,  libpng dll's and zlib1.dll's need to be added to the bin subdirectory of the emacs folder. The version number and name of the libpng dll's needed can be obtained by evaluating

```
(cdr (assq 'png dynamic-library-alist))
```

These can be obtained at https://mirror.freedif.org/GNU/emacs/windows/. For me the zip file needed was emacs-25-x86_64-deps.zip.

Choose the appropriate file depending on your system, unzip it, and copy/paste the dll's mentioned above to the bin sub directory as mentioned before.